# Connect to remote MySQL using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, mysql, sqlite, xamarin

I know that there is some post about my problem in the net, but none of them has the answer I can use.

My problem is connecting to remote MySQL database using Android Xamarin.

I tried to connect using MySQL.Data.dll - there were a lot of errors about missing references.

I wanted to use SQLite, but I couldn't find any post witch shows how to use it and CONNECT to a remote database.

I cant use any PHP / HTTP script.

Is it possible to connect to MySQL using SQLite? If yes, how to do it (I need to read and update data)?

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are totally different database platform. SQLite is generally used for local database in xamarin mobile application. you are saying like 'how to connect MySQL using Oracle?' it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting directly to an sql database, perhaps use some sort of web API to communicate?

So instead of:
Xamarin app -> MySQL db.

It'll be:
Xamarin app -> web API -> MySQL db.